# How to convert binary data in Sql Server database back to image.used Memory Stream. It saved and now trying to retrieve from Sql Server

Tags: c#

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connect.ConnectionStr);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();

        try
        {

            con.Open();

            command.Connection = con;

            if (txtFullName.Text == "")
            {
                ///
            }
            else if (txtUsername.Text == "")
            {
                ///
            }
            else if (txtPassword.Text == "")
            {
                //
            }
            else if (txtConfirm.Text == "")
            {
                //
            }
            //else if (picStaffImage.Image == null)
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show("Please upload image");
            //}
            else if (cmbStationOptn.Text == "")
            {
                //
            }
            else
            {


                Image img = picStaffImage.Image;
                byte[] arr;
                ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
                arr = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));



                string passinsert = " INSERT INTO TblUSERNAMEANDPASSWORD " +
                                     "(FullName,UserName,Password,ConfirmPassword,Image,StationOfOperation)" +
                                     "VALUES ('" + txtFullName.Text + "', " +
                                     "'" + txtUsername.Text + "'," +
                                     " '" + txtPassword.Text + "'," +
                                     " '" + txtConfirm.Text + "' ," +
                                     " '"+ arr +"', " +
                                     " '" + cmbStationOptn.Text + "' ) ";

                command = new SqlCommand(passinsert, con);

                command.ExecuteReader();

                MessageBox.Show("Username and Password has been saved");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

I created a class like this

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
namespace SDDAPP
{
    class ImageConvert
    {
        public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
        {

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn)
            {
                return Image.FromStream(stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am reading the binary data from SQL Server Database using the SqlDatareader.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connect.ConnectionStr);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader reader;

    //In a try catch block
    try
    {

            txtConfirm.Text = (string)reader["Pass$$"];                          
            picStaffImage.Image = (Image)reader["MyImage"]; //Get the image
            ImageConvert.ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn); //Goes to the ImageConvert to retrieve image in byte

            picStaffImage.Image = ImageConvert.ByteArrayToImage(ImageConvert.ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn); //I want to convert back to image//Error the best overload method has some invalid argument 'byteArrayToImageByte'has some invalid arguments

            picStaffImage.Image = (Image)reader.[(picStaffImage.Image)];
            cmbStationOptn.Text = (string)reader["StationOfOperation"];                         
    }
    reader.Close();
    command.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is your code doing that tells you something is wrong?

Comment: The code is supposed to convert binary data in sql database back to an image and placed in a picture box.

Comment: I am using sqldatareader to read from database, but must convert from its binary back to an image before placing it in a picture box.

Comment: I am using sqldatareader to read from database, but must convert from its binary back to an image before placing it in a picture box(picStaffImage). The code save images in picture box(on a GUI form) in sqldatabase. Now I want to retrieve the images from the sqldatabase. Error is 'The best overload method has some invalid arguments 'byteArrayToImage' has some invalid arguments.' I am new in C#. Your help would mostly be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the code inside your `try` block is invalid. Your `ByteArrayToImage` method looks fine. Change your try catch to this:

```
//In a try catch block
try
{
        txtConfirm.Text = (string)reader["Pass$$"];                          
        picStaffImage.Image = ImageConvert.ByteArrayToImage((byte[])reader["MyImage"]); 
        cmbStationOptn.Text = (string)reader["StationOfOperation"];                         
}
catch {}
```

You are also missing a close parentheses in your using line.

```
    public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
                                                                  ^
        {
            return Image.FromStream(stream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it. Now from the ImageConvert class

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it. Now from the ImageConvert class it reads 'Parameter not valid'. Error form the local variable stream. Tried other methods, which doesn't work

Comment: Is it `picStaffImage.Image = ImageConvert.ByteArrayToImage((byte[])reader["MyImage"]);` or `return Image.FromStream(stream);` that is giving you that error?

Comment: return Image.FromStream(stream); //that is the error:  "Parameter not valid"

Comment: You are missing a close paren at the end of `using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn)`

Comment: I have used the close parenthesis. But, It still gives an error 'Parameter not valid' at the 'return Image.FromStream(stream)' . Further research has led me to use 'stream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);' and  'Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(stream);' before the 'return Image.FromStream(stream);' .But the same error. SeekOrigin.Begin is used to find the begining and end of stream. Bitmap work with pixel data. That is what I have added before the  return type object. How do I correct such an error 'Parameter not valid'