# Invalid Expression term 'byte' (C# code)

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve my images stored in SQL-Server (in binary) using a search button.

```
private void *button_*Click(object sender, *Event* e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connect.Connec);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader reader;
try
  {

if (reader.HasRows)
    {
     while (reader.Read())
         {            
              picStaffImage.Image = (Image)reader["Image"]; //Get the image
              ImageConvert.ByteArrayToImage(byte[1] (byteArrayIn)); //Goes to the ImageConvert to retrieve image in byte
              picStaffImage.Image = (Image)reader[ImageConvert.ByteArrayToImage(byte[1](byteArrayIn))];

       cmbStationOptn.Text = (string)reader["StationOfOperation"];

                        }
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                    command.Dispose();
  }
}
```

The class is as follows:

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace Dexter
{
    class ImageConvert
    {
        public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
        {

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
            {
                return Image.FromStream(stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What the code is trying to do is that it is retrieving images stored in binary in SQL-Server database. It converts from binary back to image placing it in its picturebox called picStaffImage.

Here how I save the images.

```
 else
 {


   Image img = picStaffImage.Image;
   byte[] arr;
   ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
   arr = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
   string pass = " INSERT INTO *table* " + "(Image,Operation)" +
   "VALUES ('" + txtFullName.Text + "', " +
   " '"+ arr +"', " +
   " '" + cmbStationOptn.Text + "' ) ";
  command = new SqlCommand(pass,con);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where does byteArrayIn in your Click Handler come from and how its defined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert binary data in Sql Server database back to image.used Memory Stream. It saved and now trying to retrieve from Sql Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649043/how-to-convert-binary-data-in-sql-server-database-back-to-image-used-memory-stre)

Answer (score 0):

I answered your previous posting of this problem earlier...

[Your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649043/how-to-convert-binary-data-in-sql-server-database-back-to-image-used-memory-stre?noredirect=1#comment49391204_30649043)